# LoadTesting ASP.NET MVC 3 application with ACS authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, azure, load-testing, acs

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that is using Windows Azure ACS for authentication.  I am looking to performance and load test this application.  How do I create a test that will work through the ACS authentication process.  I have went through recording performance test and then adding it to a load test with 25 users but it seems to fail when running concurrently.  Is there some trick to dealing with the concurrency of logins.

I'm fairly sure the issue ends up being that the test is hard-coding the token and the token is not valid at some point.

Answer (score 0):

For the time of testing, you may extend the lifetime of the token. The default is 600 seconds (10 minutes), which obviously expires between the time you record and the time test runs. Token lifetime is a setting of the Relying Party:

[image: ACS Token LifeTime]

This migt help you solve the issue. Just do not forget that it is not advisable to have long-living tokens for production environment!

Comment: The token lifetime is not the issue.  The recorded test hard codes the communication between ACS and Google for instance.  Also it appears that it is using the same instance of the client because it starts to fail after the first run because the return urls are different I believe because we are already logged in for the 2nd concurrent user.